# Any way to be notified for a new version of a vim plugin?

Tags: vim, gvim

I have a bunch of vim plug-ins installed. I want to get a notification when a new version comes out. Each plugin page on vim.org (e.g., http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3025) doesn't have an RSS feed.

How do you keep your vim plugins updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about installing a plugin WHICH updates the plugins? :) Just a hunch though. (Found it with Google, I don't really use plugins: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=642)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [Vimana](http://github.com/c9s/Vimana) a command-line vim plugin/script manager, it needs perl/cpan to run